# Railscast Login Remember me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i followed the revised railcast and then decided to upgrade my code with a remember feature. Almost work but When going to the login page I get the following error

```
Couldn't find Customer with auth_token = 
Note I change the table from User to Customer
```

Here my code, maybe i made a little mistake. I did a reset on the database

Customer Controller

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
  end

  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
    if @customer.save
    session[:customer_id] = @customer.id
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

end
```

Session Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
  def create
    customer = Customer.find_by_email(params[:email])
      if customer && customer.authenticate(params[:password])
      if params[:remember_me]
         cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = customer.auth_token
      else
        cookies[:auth_token] = customer.auth_token
      end
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

Route.rb

```
  get 'signup', to: 'customers#new', as: 'signup'
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
  resources :sessions
  resources :customers    
  root :to => 'sessions#new'
```

Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  private

    def authorize
        redirect_to login_url, alert: "Not authorized" if current_customer.nil?
    end

    def current_customer
      @current_customer ||= Customer.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
    end
    helper_method :current_customer
end
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Why not use devise or auth_logic for authentication? No sense in recreating the wheel.

Comment: Because i am looking for full control, i don't want these gem to be to much in my app

Comment: It is good to write the authentication by yourself the first time to learn more about it and be able to customize\tailor it.

Comment: Devise allows you full control, stays out of the way when you don't want it, and is highly configurable.

Comment: Seems that the `cookies[:auth_token]` is empty, so you can't retrieve the user. You may have logged with a Customer where the `auth_token` was not set (due to the database reset ?). Check that all Customer have their `auth_token` filled, then logout and login again.

Comment: I understand, but this should give me the power I need for the application, but i do understand in the code that i cannot find the customer with auth_token because i have no customer created at the moment, but how can i fix that?

Comment: what I did is db:reset, then just log in to the page which points to a new sessions#new but how i am suppose to fill auth_token of a customer that doesn't exists

Comment: You could also check put sorcery. Ryan bates made a casts about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was in the following code

```
def current_customer
      @current_customer ||= Customer.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
    end
```

and fixing it by the following

```
def current_customer
      @current_customer ||= Customer.find_by_auth_token(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
    end
```